# Project won't run after name change

Tags: ios, xcode6, rename

I changed my project name with refractor on the side bar under Identity and type. Everything changed accordingly. However, my test target runs into an error:

```
clang: error: no such file or directory:'/Users/E/Downloads/GalaxyRun/GameTutorial/GameTutorial-Prefix.pch'
clang: error: no input files
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1
```

What can I do to fix this? I am using iOS 8.

Comment: how did you refactor your project's name?

Comment: Clicked on my project, on the sidebar to the right, under identity and type, I changed the name and Xcode refactored for me. @holex

Comment: and why don't you just rename the `.pch` file manually?

Comment: just tried it, still the same error

Answer (score 1):

I've faced a similar problem today. You need to fix it manually. Search for **GameTutorial-Prefix.pch** and change it with your new name.

[image]

Comment: Just tried your method and ended up with a similar error: ld: file not found: /Users/E/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GalaxyRun-gecyucqrichnavaryykscedfhltu/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/GameTutorial.app/GameTutorial
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: You also need to change app name like Debug-iphonesimulator/NewName.app/NewName

Comment: It's in linking section and you need to clean deriveddata after that.

Comment: Man...XCode is the worst IDE I have ever used.

Comment: On the Apple App Store, Xcode is rated only 3 stars.  :-D